# Copy highlighted element from <select>

Tags: javascript, html-select

Can anyone please let me know that how do I copy a highlighted/selected `option` element from one `select` tag to another `select` on `click` of a button using JavaScript (not jQuery)?

The select tag has the `size` attribute, hence it's not a drop down.

```js
function copy_all() {
  var roleList = document.getElementById("roles");
  var asgned_roles = document.getElementById("asgndroles");
  asgned_roles.innerHTML = roleList.innerHTML;
}

function copy_selected() {
  var selected = document.getElementsByTagName("OPTION");
  var asgned_roles = document.getElementById("asgndroles");
  if (selected.hasFocus()) {
    asgned_roles.innerHTML = selected.innerHTML;
  }
}
```

```html
<select size="5" id="roles">
  <option>Admin</option>
  <option>User</option>
  <option>Super User</option>
  <option>Super Admin</option>
</select>
<select size="5" id="asgndroles">
</select>
<button onclick="copy_selected()">COPY</button>
<button onclick="copy_all()">COPY ALL</button>
```

Comment: Hi SSinha! We would love to help, but please elaborate and provide code for your question. It isn't clear what you mean.

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow — we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems — but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: I am unable to attach my code in comment hence attaching it in  the question  section.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8zoqxnh2/3/
copy_selected() is not working. I need to copy the highlighted /chosen <option>under first <select> inside another <select> element.

Comment: The correct place to add the relevant code is the body of the question. Comments are not fit to the task and links to external sources can break. I have edited your question to include the jsfiddle as a SO snippet. Also, please, note how I have edited the text to correctly highlight the code keywords. Moreover, you don't need to include "JavaScript" in the title since you already tagged the question.

Comment: I don't think that this question deserves to keep on being downvoted so hard after it has been edited (before yes, it did). I have the feeling that some SO users are like sharks: they smell the blood.

Answer (score 0):

To get the `index` of the selected `option` element use the [`selectedIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedIndex) property.

To append the option to the target `select` use the [`appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) method.

To remove the option from the source `select` use the [`removeChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild) method.

```js
var source_select = document.getElementById("roles");
var target_select = document.getElementById("asgndroles");

function copy_selected() {
  var selected_option = source_select.options[source_select.selectedIndex];
  source_select.removeChild(selected_option);
  target_select.appendChild(selected_option);
}
```

```html
<select size="5" id="roles">
  <option>Admin</option>
  <option>User</option>
  <option>Super User</option>
  <option>Super Admin</option>
</select>
<select size="5" id="asgndroles">
</select>
<button onclick="copy_selected()">COPY</button>
```

Comment: @SSinha - You are welcome! Consider to accept the answer if it helped you.